# NLP in python for food

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I need to make a script for NLP in python. Given a string, I need to identify the food and output the calories. I thought of using a csv dataset and creating a model with tensorflow to identify the food. it's correct? do you think we can do another way?

Do you have examples or suggestions?

thank you

Comment: I would recommend using NLP in classifying food. You can read this article which uses NLP for cuisine classification: https://medium.com/swlh/nlp-project-cuisine-classification-topic-modelling-cd7b4c734b19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use NER model to identify food in the string, and then you use the identified food to check the repository which has food calories for respective food item and share the output.